# Sam goes to the movies

Tags: grammar

1. Sam goes to the movies once a month.

---

What does 'the movies' mean in this sentence?

a. a movie theater
b. a showing of a movie in a theater 
c. films in general
d. the film industry

Answer (score 1):

The expression **going to the movies** would be widely understood to mean going to watch a movie in a movie theatre - also known as **going to a film**.

One might also use the expression regarding the showing of a movie in a school hall or similar but it would be stretching the meaning.

So the answer is definitely "b".

It would NOT be understood as:

a. going to a movie theatre for some other purpose

c. films in general

d. the movie industry.